# On click pass through result to hidden field for each q?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Doing the following:

```
$(".questionOne").click(function(){

    var answer=$(this).attr('href').split('=')[1]
    $('#questionOne').val( answer );

       return false;
});
```

How do I go about repeating it for each question rather than typing it out 30 times? I have 30 questions, that are yes or no with links that send a result to a hidden field, but can't for the life of me remember how to get it do repeat the function for each clicked answer.

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Have a look at .each() function in jquery. Loop it over all your questions.

Comment: Here's my jsfidde http://jsfiddle.net/wqpjme1L/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there aren't any other elements containing the word 'question' in their class, you can use the attribute selector `[class*="question"]` to select the elements. Then just get the clicked element's class and select the other elements based on that `id`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/w3yuv4Lw/) - HTML unchanged.

```
$('a[class*="question"]').on('click', function () {
    var answer = $(this).attr('href').split('=')[1];
    $('#' + $(this).prop('class')).val(answer);

    return false;
});
```

In this case, `data-*` attributes would be better than classes.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you Josh. I'm guessing this takes the value from the class after "question" and assigns it to the input field?

Comment: @BN83 Yep. It does what your initial example did. See the [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/w3yuv4Lw/).

Comment: I did see the example, I just wanted to confirm what the code was actually doing rather than just using it.

Comment: @BN83 Ah. That's good. Often times people will just copy/paste and move on without understanding it :p

Answer (score 2):

Give all your questions a class, e.g. `class="question"`. Then you can write it just once:

```
$(".question").click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href').split('=');
    var question = href[0].substr(2); // skip over #?
    var answer = href[1];
    $("#"+question).val(answer);
    return false;
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/wqpjme1L/4/)

Comment: I've done that here: http://jsfiddle.net/wqpjme1L/1/ but it doesn't seem to receive the file to the input?

Comment: Something's not right here. `href` is for `<a>` tags, but `.val()` is for `<input>` tags. What is `$("#questionOne")`?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish with `$("#questionOne").val(answer)`?

Comment: #questionOne is an input tag. In this: http://jsfiddle.net/wqpjme1L/ It works correctly, but I have to type out the same code but changing the receiving click and destination input.

Comment: Ahh, I was confused by you using `questionOne` as both a class and ID, I didn't notice that.

Comment: Updated the answer and tested it in your fiddle